# Filter table column angular js based on drop down

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<form class="col2">
        <label for="filter-online">
             Filter by Online 
        </label>
        <div class="select">
           <select id="filter-online" ng-model="vm.online" class="form-control" ng-options="online for online in vm.onlines">
              <option value="">All</option>
           </select>
        </div>
</form>

<form class="col2">
       <label for="filter-productType">
              Filter by Product Type
       </label>
       <div class="select">
            <select id="filter-productType" ng-model="vm.productType" class="form-control" ng-options="productType for productType in vm.productTypes">
                 <option value="">All</option>
            </select>
       </div>
</form>

<tr ng-repeat="lim in vm.stockLimits track by lim.id">
      <td>{{lim.online}}</td>
      <td>{{lim.producttype}}</td>
</tr>

 vm.stockLimits values below:
 ONLINE PRODUCT TYPE
 Men    Shirt
 Men    Shoe
 Ladies Top
 Kids   belt
 Kids   
 ..........
 ..........
```

Based on drop down (filter_online select & filter_productType select), need to filter data in the  table.
 Is it possible to write one custom filter javascript function in angular script file which can be used to filter both online & product type based on drop down selection? It would be great if you show me the ideas of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a custom filter on your `ng-repeat` in such a way that it can filter out selected values dynamically from the dropdown selection.

Here's the `ng-repeat`:

```
ng-repeat="lim in vm.stockLimits | filter:{
             online:vm.online && vm.online !== '' ? vm.online : '', 
             productType: vm.productType && vm.productType !== '' ? vm.productType : ''
          }"
```

Find working code snippet below!

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.onlines = ["Men", "Kids", "Ladies"];
    vm.productTypes = ["Shirt", "Shoe", "Top"];
    vm.stockLimits = [{
      id: 1,
      online: "Men",
      productType: "Shirt"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      online: "Men",
      productType: "Shoe"
    }, {
      id: 3,
      online: "Kids",
      productType: "Belt"
    }, {
      id: 4,
      online: "Ladies",
      productType: "Top"
    }]
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
  <form class="col2">
    <label for="filter-online">
    Filter by Online 
  </label>
    <div class="select">
      <select id="filter-online" ng-model="vm.online" class="form-control" ng-options="online for online in vm.onlines">
        <option value="">All</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>

  <form class="col2">
    <label for="filter-productType">
    Filter by Product Type
  </label>
    <div class="select">
      <select id="filter-productType" ng-model="vm.productType" class="form-control" ng-options="productType for productType in vm.productTypes">
      <option value="">All</option>
    </select>
    </div>
  </form>

  <table style="margin-top: 30px">
    <tr ng-repeat="lim in vm.stockLimits | filter:{online:vm.online && vm.online !== '' ? vm.online : '', productType: vm.productType && vm.productType !== '' ? vm.productType : ''}">
      <td>{{lim.online}}</td>
      <td>{{lim.productType}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It works great but productType can be null. If productType is empty, filtering is not happening properly.

Comment: @user2057006 okay. Can you make a fiddle/plunker of that using my code above to point what exactly happens? I'll look and try to help you out in the morning.. Also, please mark answer accepted if it helped.. Thanks!

Comment: It helped but productType can be empty in the input. for e.g. {
      id: 5,
      online: "Kids",
      productType: ''
    }

Comment: @user2057006 I tried removing it from `Kids`, filter worked fine for me. What exactly happens with you?

Comment: If i have input { id: 5, online: "Kids", productType: null }. Its not filtering as expected.

Comment: why put null and not empty string instead?

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJS you can stack as many filters on an array as you would like on an array.

Try doing something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<select ng-model="vm.online" ng-options="online for online in vm.onlines" ng-change="vm.filterChanged()">
    <option value="">All</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="vm.productType" ng-options="productType for productType in vm.productTypes" ng-change="vm.filterChanged()">
    <option value="">All</option>
</select>

<tr ng-repeat="lim in vm.filteredStockLimits = vm.stockLimits | filterByOnline:vm.online
        | filterByProductType:vm.productType track by lim.id">
```

**JS (Controller):**

```
var filterChanged = function() {
        var filtered = $filter('filterByOnline')(vm.stockLimits, vm.online);
        vm.filteredStockLimits = $filter('filterByProductType')(filtered, vm.productType);
}
```

In your controller you read the data into your initial `vm.stockLimits` array which gets filtered into `vm.filteredStockLimits` when either select box is changed. Note, you will have to add two custom filters (`filterByOnline` and `filterByProductType`) to filter the array by the online and product type. For that you can reference the AngularJS docs: [AngularJS Custom Filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-show` or `ng-if` to filter data.

no need to create a custom filter.

something like this.

```js
<tr ng-repeat="lim in vm.stockLimits" ng-show="lim.productType==vm.productType && lim.online==vm.online">
    <td>{{lim.online}}</td>
    <td>{{lim.productType}}</td>
  </tr>
```

see full workin fiddle here
[http://jsfiddle.net/SNF9x/315/](http://Demo)

Comment: Thanks for the response but data itself is not displaying in table grid after use the given snippet.

Comment: can u make a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Better you can use npm package of filter;

install it:- npm i ng2-search-filter

import this to module.ts

import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from 'ng2-search-filter';

in html : *ngFor="let dealerdata of Dealer_data|filter:Status|filter:Range"